# What does ==> mean in proverif?

Tags: verification, formal-methods

I found the following line of code in the proverif manual.

```
 ⋮ 
query event(evCocks) ==> event(evRSA).
 ⋮
```

What does `==>` mean?

`EDIT: I have answered my own question below.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Correspondence properties:
  P and Q are predicates.

    P(x) ==> Q(x, y)

      for all x where P(x) is true, then there exists a y 
      such that Q(x, y) is true
```

```
query event(e1) ==> event(e2).

  the query above can be translated to the following question:
    Is it true that;
         for all executions of event e1 (in the protocol) it is true that 
         e2 has executed?
```

In the proverif manual it is stated that

```
query event(evCocks) ==> event(evRSA)

is true if and only if, for all executions of the protocol, if the event 
evCocks has been executed, then
event evRSA has also [already] been executed
```

[link to proverif manual](https://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/bblanche/proverif/manual.pdf)